# Highlight ONLY THE FIRST of all min/max values in a row/column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to `THE TITLE`, that would be the general question; in my specific situation I need the minimum value in each row of a matrix, using conditional formatting of course.

I've only been able to go as far as highlighting *all* of the minimum values in each row. Example:

[image]

in the picture you see matrix ***G5:I28*** being affected by this rule:

**=G5=MIN($G5:$I28)**

applied to

**=$G$5:$I$28**

using the conditional formatting dialog box.

The issue remains trying to achieve, in the fourth row in the picture for instance, that only the second cell's background is highlighted (the first **1** in the row); and so on for every row.

So far I've tried combinations of **MATCH**, **ADDRESS**, **LARGE**, **SMALL**, **MIN**, **MAX**, etc, to no avail.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data columns are A:C and your first data row is row 1, you could use a rule:

```
=COLUMN()=MATCH(MIN($A1:$C1),$A1:$C1,0)
```

This will find the minimum value in the row, then find the first cell in the row matching that value.  If the cell's column number is the same, it will apply the format.

You can create the conditional format for the first row, then copy, paste-special format to the rest of the range.

[image]

**Range translation for different worksheet location**

MATCH produces a result relative to it's own range definition (first cell in range = position 1, regardless of its location on the worksheet). If the actual columns are G:I, the first column in your worksheet range is column 7, so the formula needs to be shifted by 6 columns.  You can either add 6 to the match result or subtract 6 from the column number for comparison. You could use either:

```
=COLUMN()=MATCH(MIN($G1:$I1),$G1:$I1,0)+6
```

or

```
=COLUMN()-6=MATCH(MIN($G1:$I1),$G1:$I1,0)
```

The row number isn't a factor, so for row 5, the row references would be `5` instead of `1` in the formulas.

In a comment, you asked about making this more generic, so it would remain correct if you insert a column.  That adds another dimension to any formula; you basically need to replace hard-coded adjustments with formulas.

Instead of a fixed adjustment of `6`, you could use the current number of first column minus `1`.  If you insert or delete columns, range references are automatically adjusted.  So you could use:

```
=COLUMN()=MATCH(MIN($G1:$I1),$G1:$I1,0)+COLUMN($G1)-1
```

Comment: it works on range *A1:C1* but not with *G5:I5*, for which I need it so then I can apply it to each row in *G5:I28*, there might be another factor to take into consideration like maybe the fact that `MATCH` returns relative values starting from 1, I can't seem to crack it

Comment: @Scaramouche, MATCH produces a result relative to it's own range definition (first cell in range = position 1, regardless of its location on the worksheet).  If the actual columns are G:I, the first column in your worksheet range is column 7.  So you can either add 6 to the match result or subtract 6 from the column number for comparison.  You could use either: `=COLUMN()=MATCH(MIN($G1:$I1),$G1:$I1,0)+6` or `=COLUMN()-6=MATCH(MIN($G1:$I1),$G1:$I1,0)`

Comment: accepted, could you please crank it up a notch and think of a way of making that `6` relative to the range, I tried replacing it with `COLUMN()-1` but didn't work. Ideally I would be able to insert for example, a column somewhere before the range and the formatting would still work, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on [fixer1234's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1396236/675927) which explains the main idea to solve my problem. Here I include the solution which worked for me to make the formatting *move* accordingly every time a column is inserted to the left of the matrix.

fixer1234's solution: `=COLUMN()=MATCH(MIN($A1:$C1),$A1:$C1,0)`

changing `A1` and `C1` to the desired row range (not very important) and adding `+COLUMN($G$3)-1` to the formula (very important) to add relativity to it, resulting in:

```
=COLUMN()=MATCH(MIN($G3:$I3),$G3:$I3,0)+COLUMN($G$3)-1
```

Note: `$G$3` is the first cell in my matrix.

Hope it helps.